# How to merge rows into one row with separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need merge rows into one row for summary of calculation (SQL Server 2014).

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
    [c].[Iso],
    SUM([r].[Quantity]) AS [Quantity],
    SUM([r].[Amount]) AS [Amount]
FROM
    [CarReport].[dbo].[Refuelling] [r]
INNER JOIN 
    [CarReport].[dbo].[Currency] [c] ON [r].[CurrencyId] = [c].[CurrencyId]
WHERE 
    [r].[DataId] = 15
    AND [r].[IsDeleted] = 0
GROUP BY 
    [r].[CurrencyId], [c].[Iso]
```

Result of this query is:

```
CZK |   50.00 | 1350,00
EUR |   23.00 | 463,20
```

I would like to have this result:

```
CZK/EUR |   50.00/23.00 |   1350,00/463,20
```

When add new currency (x), the result of new currency must be appended:

```
CZK/EUR/x | 50.00/23.00/x | 1350,00/463,20/x
```

Can somebody please help me with this topic?

Many thanks

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Does the order of the ISO matter?  If yes, then what to order by?

Comment: I have MS SQL 2014 (added to post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work with earlier versions of MSSQL as well.

```
;with subQuery as (
    -- paste your base query here
    -- extend it with one additional column:
    -- ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISO) RowNum
) 
select
    (select stuff((select '/' + convert(nvarchar(max), Iso) from subQuery order by RowNum for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')),
    (select stuff((select '/' + convert(nvarchar(max), Quantity) from subQuery order by RowNum for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')),
    (select stuff((select '/' + convert(nvarchar(max), Amount) from subQuery order by RowNum for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are running SQL Server 2017, you can add another level of aggregation and use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG([Iso], '/') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [Iso]) AS [Iso],
    STRING_AGG([Quantity], '/') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [Iso]) AS [Quantity],
    STRING_AGG([Amount], '/') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [Iso]) AS [Amount]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [c].[Iso],
        SUM([r].[Quantity]) AS [Quantity]
        SUM([r].[Amount]) AS [Amount]
    FROM
        [CarReport].[dbo].[Refuelling] [r]
    INNER JOIN 
        [CarReport].[dbo].[Currency] [c] ON [r].[CurrencyId] = [c].[CurrencyId]
    WHERE 
        [r].[DataId] = 15
        AND [r].[IsDeleted] = 0
    GROUP BY 
        [r].[CurrencyId], [c].[Iso]
) t
```

The `ORDER BY` clause of `STRING_AGG()` gives you a consistent ordering of values accross the different columns, so you can tell which quantity and amount belong to which currency (if that matters).

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your code, and missed information about version of SQL. I have MS SQL 2014 (added to post), this version
does not contains STRING_AGG function.